# How do I install grub to a usb stick from linux?

Tags: usb, fedora, grub

I want to install GRUB (I don't care what version) to my 16 GB USB stick. 
I'm running Fedora 17 (Beefy Miracle) GNOME.

I can't find any way to do it on YouTube or Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to just mount the drive and then check which one with `sudo fdisk -l`.  Afterward, you can run the installer with:

```
grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sdX
```

That is assuming you use GRUB as your loader on your fedora box.

Don't specify the partition # on it since you probably want it on the device as a whole.

Comment: Didn't work I got  [root@Mypc Myuser]# grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sdb
bash: grub-install: command not found...
[root@Mypc myuser]#             GRUB is my bootloader

Comment: @BigglesCat5 Try typing `gr` and hit tab a few times.  Your system should show you the executables that are linked.  Do you see any grub related ones?

Comment: I found GRUB2-Install it wouldnt work so i formatted my usb EXT4 and it worked Thanks!